# Meteor and Iron-router: subscription lifetimes

Tags: meteor, iron-router

As far as I can tell, when I suscribe to a result set inside an iron-router hook, like before: or waitOn:, it works fine, but it seems to get torn down, as soon as another route runs.  Does anyone know if this is what happens?

Assuming it is, does that mean that only way to make a subscription persist across routes is to subscribe somewhere OTHER than the Router.map() function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to re-subscribe if you want to maintain the subscription between routes. An easy way to achieve this is to use [Controllers](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#route-controllers). It is also worth mentioning that Iron-Router/Meteor is smart enough to know when you're re-using the same subscriptions between routes so they don't load again.

One way you can do it:

```
ProjectController = RouteController.extend({
    before: [
        function() {
            this.subscribe("project.comments", this.params.projectId).wait();
            this.subscribe("project.log", this.params.projectId).wait();
        }
    ]
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('project.overview', {
    path: '/project/:projectId/overview',
    controller: 'ProjectController'
  });

  this.route('project.tasks', {
    path: '/project/:projectId/tasks',
    controller: 'ProjectController'
  });
});
```

Now the "project.overview" and "project.tasks" routes will subscribe to "project.comments" and "project.log".

You can then make a route specific controller and extend from "ProjectController" to make route specific subscriptions:

```
ProjectController = RouteController.extend({
    before: [
        function() {
            this.subscribe("project.comments", this.params.projectId).wait();
            this.subscribe("project.log", this.params.projectId).wait();
        }
    ]
});

ProjectOverviewController = ProjectController.extend({
    before: [
        function() {
            this.subscribe("project.stats", this.params.projectId).wait();
        }
    ]
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('project.overview', {
    path: '/project/:projectId/overview',
    controller: 'ProjectOverviewController'
  });

  this.route('project.tasks', {
    path: '/project/:projectId/tasks',
    controller: 'ProjectController'
  });
});
```

The "project.overview" route will now subscribe to "project.comments", "project.log" and "project.stats".

Another way you can do it if you need an application wide subscription is to use the "Router.before" hook (https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#using-hooks):

```
Router.before(function() {
    this.subscribe("global.sub");
});
```

Comment: Great.  I never really understood the whole controller thing before, but this makes it much clearer than the docs that I read.  So, this is an extremely flexible solution and jacksondc offers a fast and easy solution below that works when your needs are simpler.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a subscription for all routes in `Router.configure`:

```
Router.configure({
    waitOn: function() { 
        return Meteor.subscribe('my-subscription');
    }
});
```